# Rails cache method result queried through many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a player model which can belong to several teams.
A team belongs to one category and has a color. 
A player can have a color too.
A player can belong to one team per category.
The user can optionally set a category as 'primary' which means the colors from this category will be used.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_memberships
  has_many :teams, :through => 'team_memberships'
  has_many :categories, :through => 'teams'
end

class TeamMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :player
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  attr_accessible :color, :name

  has_many :team_memberships
  has_many :players, :through => :team_memberships
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
  has_many :team_memberships, :through => :teams
  has_many :players, :through => :team_memberships
end
```

I have a method that returns the player's team for a specific category and I have a method that returns the color to be displayed on the players index page. It gets the color from either the player itself, the primary team or the team from the first category available.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  def index_color
    if self[:color].blank?
      if self.categories.size > 0
        if self.categories.primary.size > 0
          return self.team_for(self.categories.primary.first).color
        else
          return self.team_for(self.categories.first).color
        end
      end
    else
      return self[:color]
    end
  end

  def team_for(cat)
    teams_ids = cat.teams.map{|team| team.id}
    membership = TeamMembership.where(:player_id => self.id, :team_id => [team_ids]).first
    if membership
      return membership.team
    else
      return nil
    end
  end
end
```

As I have a lot of players this color request slows down the display of my index page quite a lot. Since this rarely changes I want to cache the result.
I tried to encapsulate the method using Rails.cache.fetch

```
def index_color
  Rails.cache.fetch("players/#{self.id}/color") do
  ...
  end
end
```

But it doesn't appear to work as I still have hundreds of queries to TeamMembership spawned from the index_color method. I also tried to cache the result of the team_for method but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to actually set `teams.color` on update instead? So that you evaluate it when a team is created or a category is added? The advantage here being that you are only dealing with a single record vs doing it on an index of records.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, the index_color method is in the Player model, team.color is defined upon creation. The player index_color should be it's own color if defined (almost never) or it's primary team color if a primary category is defined or it's first category's team color.

Comment: Ok, then can you instead set `player.color` or a `player.default_color` when it is associated with a team or category? However else you go about this you're still going to have to deal with a nasty n+1 issue or joining in tons of data on your index page.

Comment: I thought about that but it will slow down my team assignation and team updates action quite a lot which is not something I want either. So there is no way to cache this method result ?